# Using variables to check for error condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, if-statement

I have a personal simple jQuery validation script.

It works when the submit button is clicked and sets up a variable:
`$errors = false;`

Then there are series of `if` statements that check for textbox values and conditions, and if conditions are not met, variable `$errors` is set to `true`.

The script works except for one thing. If all textbox conditions are met (correlating to false $error variable), the script does not send the form. This is how the script ends:

```
    if ( ($errors = true) ) {
        return false;
    }
    else if ( ($errors != true) ) {
        //nothing
        return true;
}
```

I've tried removing the `return true;`, replacing it with `return`, and nothing worked. Why does it not send the form?!? It's as if it's constantly stuck on the `return false;` location.

Now, if I comment out `return false;`, the script shows the errors and sends the form. Obviously we don't want to send the form if there are errors.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!
Amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For comparison you're supposed to use `==` which compares not `=` which assigns. Since you assign it, it always becomes true.

Comment: Somebody should create a bot that would grep SO for `if[\\( ]+[^=]+=[^=]+[\\)& ]+` and put up this answer. Or did You meder? :) 
And the bot would post "use parser" when found regex and html in one question :D

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that it should be

```
if ( ($errors == true) ) {
```

instead of

```
if ( ($errors = true) ) {
```

Comment: Yes you're right. That's exactly what meder said. Thank you. Fixed :)